# Не запускаются .jar файлы экспортированные в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Я экспортировал свой проект в runnable jar file в Eclipse. Правильно указал входной класс. Все библиотеки добавлены. Файл не запускается. Другой jar файл который я когда-то делал в нетбинсе запускается без проблем. Что делать?

Comment: Как минимум предоставить больше вводных, описывающих проблему.

Comment: Как запускаете? И что происходит когда запускаете?

Comment: Просмотрите старый добрый ресурс: http://skipy.ru/technics/likbez.html#lookup

Comment: Запускаю двойным щелчком. Ничего не происходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй запустить свой jar через консоль и посмотреть вывод программы:

```
java -jar my_program.jar
```

Если программа не запускается, но должна, в выводе обязательно будет что-то, что подскажет тебе причину возникших неполадок.

Comment: оказывается нужно было вручную перенести все файлы (картинки, модели) в папку с .jar файлом